# JOINS and absentee values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, join, null

```
INSERT INTO Shipments (Column1...Column200)

SELECT
       O.Value1,...
       CL.Value199,
       isnull(P.PriceFactor1,1)

FROM   Orders O
       JOIN Clients CL on O.ClientNo = CL.ClientNo
       JOIN Calc C on CL.CalcCode = C.CalcCode
       JOIN Prices P on CL.PriceKey = P.PriceKey
WHERE  O.PriceFactor1 = P.PriceFactor1
       AND O.PriceFactor2 = P.PriceFactor2
       AND O.PriceFactor3 = P.PriceFactor3
```

The above query (part of a new stored procedure meant to replace an old and nasty one that used a cursor...) fails to return some rows, because the rows in Orders do not have matching rows in Prices.  In such cases, we want the last value in the INSERT list to be 1 by default.  Instead, the row is never built; or, when we tried to fix it by changing the WHERE conditions, it brought PriceFactor1 from a different row, which is also no good.

How it's supposed to work:

A row is created in table Orders.  A third-party program then executes a stored procedure (Asp_BuildShipments) and displays the results once they have been inserted into table Shipments.  This SP is meant to populate the table Shipments by pulling values from Orders, Clients, Drivers, Vehicles, Prices, Routes, and others.  It's a long SP, and the array of tables is big and varied.

```
In table Orders:
PriceFactor1  |  PriceFactor2  |  PriceFactor3
12            |  10            |  8

In table Prices:
PriceFactor1  |  PriceFactor2  |  PriceFactor3
18            |  12            |  10
```

In a case such as this, the SP needs to recognize that no such rows exist in Prices and use a default value of 1 rather than skipping the row or pulling the price from a different row.

We've tried isnull(), CASE statements, and WHERE EXISTS, but to no avail.

The new SP is set based, and we want to leave it that way - the old one took minutes, the new one takes only a few seconds.  But without passing row by row, we aren't sure how to check each individual Order to see if has a matching Price before building the row in Shipments.

I know there are details missing here, but I didn't want to write a 1,000 page question.  If these details are insufficient, I'll post as much as I need to to help get your brains storming.  Been stuck on this for a while now...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be as simple as:

```
SELECT
       O.Value1,...
       CL.Value199,
       isnull(P.PriceFactor1,1)

FROM   Orders O
       JOIN Clients CL on O.ClientNo = CL.ClientNo
       JOIN Calc C on CL.CalcCode = C.CalcCode
       LEFT JOIN Prices P on CL.PriceKey = P.PriceKey
           AND O.PriceFactor1 = P.PriceFactor1
           AND O.PriceFactor2 = P.PriceFactor2
           AND O.PriceFactor3 = P.PriceFactor3
```

Comment: Apparently not. It's one of the things that I tried in the beginning, hoping that it would return a NULL.  Instead, the SP doesn't build the row atall.  I believe the problem is actually the AND conditions (O.PriceFactor1...3 = P.PriceFactor1...3), but if we remove them it makes a real mess.  There must be a comparison between the pricing factors listed in Order and the ones listed in Prices, but adding these conditions seems to nullify any Orders that don't match anything in Prices in the SP's eyes.  Thanks anyway :)

Comment: A LEFT OUTER JOIN was eventually the answer, though not in the way I looked for it.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Hansell's answer should work if the problem is as you suggest there are no matching rows in Prices. Since it's not working the problem is in the other joins.

One of  these joins filters out data.

```
JOIN Clients CL on O.ClientNo = CL.ClientNo
JOIN Calc C on CL.CalcCode = C.CalcCode
```